# ¿Por qué no se guardan los registros StringRequest de Volley pasando getParams?

Tags: php, android, android-studio, android-volley

Estoy utilizando StringRequest de volley para guardar mis registros con Php este es mi codigo:
NO me regresa ningun error pero en mi base de datos el registro se guarda vacio,
¿Que puede estar mal?
tambien eh intentado usando JsonObjectRequest y ahi si se guarda mi registro correctamente pero no puedo obtener la respuesta, me muestra un error de JSONException: Value of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject

```
<?php
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
header("Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST");
header("Access-Control-Max-Age: 3600");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type, Access-Control-Allow-Headers, Authorization, X-Requested-With");

include_once 'db.php';
include_once 'deteccion.php';

$database = new Database();
$db = $database->getConnection();
$item = new Deteccopm($db);
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));
$item->email = $data->email;
 if($item->createDeteccion()){
    echo 'Deteccion ingresada exitosamente.';
} else{
    echo 'El registro no pudo ser ingresado.';
}
```

?>

Este es el codigo de StringRequest

```
i name = editTextName.getText().toString().trim();

    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, UrlService,
            new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    progressDialog.dismiss();

                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), response, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        String respuesta = response;
                        if (respuesta.equals("Deteccion ingresada exitosamente.[]")) {
                            //if there is a success
                            //storing the name to sqlite with status synced
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), response, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                            saveNameToLocalStorage(name, NAME_SYNCED_WITH_SERVER);
                        } else {
                            //if there is some error
                            //saving the name to sqlite with status unsynced
                            saveNameToLocalStorage(name, NAME_NOT_SYNCED_WITH_SERVER);

                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), response, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }

                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    progressDialog.dismiss();
                    //on error storing the name to sqlite with status unsynced
                    saveNameToLocalStorage(name, NAME_NOT_SYNCED_WITH_SERVER);

                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), error.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }) {
        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
            params.put("email", name);
            return params;
        }
    };

    VolleySingleton.getInstance(this).addToRequestQueue(stringRequest);
```

Comment: Siempre es mejor trabajar con JSON en vez de cadenas, sobre todo porque te permite organizar mejor los datos y es menos propenso a errores. Pero en ese caso respuesta desde PHP debe ser un JSON y en Android debes convertirlo para poder leerlo. Si de todos modos quieres trabajar con StringRequest depura los datos que estás recibiendo para verificar por qué no se guardan. Haz un `var_dump($data);` y revisa el Log.cat en Android.

Comment: Muchhas gracias por tu comentario, cambiando a Json con el JSONObject me funciona el registro, se guarda correctamente pero no puedo obtener la respuesta porque en Php la manda como String y no Json, entonces como yo no tengo acceso a ese Php que está publicado para poder modificarlo y devolver un json de respuesta, ¿hay forma de poder leer ese string en la respuesta? utilizando JSONObject

Comment: Ok, si el código de servidor escapa a tu control no te queda otra que dejarlo como StringRequest y ver por qué los datos no se insertan en ese caso. ¿Mandas los mismos datos en ambos casos o hay algo diferente? Realmente `StringRequest` o `JSONObjectRequest` tienen que ver con el tipo de respuesta que se recibe del servidor, pero lo que es envío de datos debería funcionar igual, independientemente del tipo de request.

Comment: Hola ismael, puedes probar pasando la respuesta con la función **toString()**

`JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(respuestaString.toString());`

donde **respuestaString** es la respuesta que obtienes desde el servidor.